# Change array objects to strings... TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, arrays, loops, 2d, ascii

So, I'm making a little game sort of like dwarf fortress... but right now im working on just making the screen change randomly. I have t being assigned to a string, and g to another. It works fine when I predefine it, but when changing it...

This is what it should, and normally outputs (without changing dynamically changing anything):

```
# # # # # # 
# ^ # # ^ # 
# # ^ # # # 
# # # # # # 
# # # # # # 
# # # ^ # #
```

(It outputs with color)

But when I try dynamically changing the array, it screws up. Here is the code:

```
import os
import time
import random
clear = lambda: os.system('clear')

g = '\033[32m' + '# '
t = '\033[31m' + '^ '
l = [g, g, g, g, g, g,
     g, t, g, g, t, g,
     g, g, t, g, g, g,
     g, g, g, g, g, g,
     g, g, g, g, g, g,
     g, g, g, t, g, g]

def level():
    i = 0
    while i < 50:
        print l[0] + l[1] + l[2] + l[3] + l[4] + l[5]
        print l[6] + l[7] + l[8] + l[9] + l[10] + l[11]
        print l[12] + l[13] + l[14] + l[15] + l[16] + l[17]
        print l[18] + l[19] + l[20] + l[21] + l[22] + l[23]
        print l[24] + l[25] + l[26] + l[27] + l[28] + l[29]
        print l[30] + l[31] + l[32] + l[33] + l[34] + l[35]
        time.sleep(0.2)
        i += 1
        for b in l:
            ch = round(random.random())
            if ch:
                l[b] = t
            else:
                l[b] = g
        clear()
level()
```

And here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DF.py", line 33, in <module>
    level()
  File "DF.py", line 29, in level
    l[b] = t
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

How could I fix this? Also, ANY tips or suggestions not regarding this question would also be greatly appreciated, im a newb at Python, so I need some pro tips :P

Also, I'm sure there's a way to print this all out in correct format without going threw the array and printing it. There's probably something with a loop, but if I just do the standard

```
for i in l:
    print l[i]
```

does not work, cuz it wont print it in a 6x6. it'll print it in a 1x36 :P 
So please help me with this little game!

Comment: By the way, a little tip. Don't use 'l' (lowercase L) alone for a variable name. In many fonts that's easy to mistake for a 1 (number one).

Comment: Two things: **1)** The `while` loop is unnecessary. Use `for i in range(50):` **2)** To print out the entire grid: `print "\n".join("".join(l[i: i + 6]) for i in range(0, len(l), 6))`

Answer (score 4):

Your main problem is here:

```
    for b in l:
        ch = round(random.random())
        if ch:
            l[b] = t
        else:
            l[b] = g
```

In Python, a `for` loop doesn't generate indices; it actually provides you with a direct reference to each of the items in the object being iterated over. So for example, if you did this:

```
for c in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    print c
```

You wouldn't get

```
1
2
3
```

You'd get

```
a
b
c
```

So when you do this: `l[b]`, you're trying to use the item in the list as if it were its own index. Also note that you won't be able to modify the list this way, which seems to be what you're trying to do. See below for more about that.

To answer your second question, one way to iterate over a list in segments is like so; there are many others, but this is probably easiest to understand when you're starting out:

```
for i in range(0, len(l), 6):
    print ' '.join(l[i:i + 6])
```

That colon in the second line *slices* the list, returning a copy of the section of the list between `i` and `i + 6`. The function `' '.join(...)` takes a list of strings and connects the strings together with a space between them.

Finally, I see that you are also trying to *modify* the list. You need to do something more. The *best* way (imho) to do that is as follows (this is just an example):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]:
for i, n in enumerate(a):
    a[i] = n * 2
```

`enumerate` is a function that allows you to iterate over indices *and* items in the list. So `i` here is the index into `a`, and `n` is the value of `a[i]`.

Comment: With that it prints the list representation. print l[i] isn't the same as print l[i][0] + l[i][1] + l[i][n]

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue, the error is on:

```
for b in l:
    ch = round(random.random())
    if ch:
        l[b] = t
    else:
        l[b] = g
```

You're trying to index by the chars themselves. You should do:

```
for i, b in enumerate(l):
    ch = round(random.random())
    if ch:
        l[i] = t
    else:
        l[i] = g
```

enumerate() will give the index for each char as you iterate over it.

Regarding the printing issue, the loop below should do it:

```
for i in xrange(0, 36, 6):
    print ''.join(l[i:i+6])
```

Or this one, if you want a one liner:

```
print '\n'.join(''.join(l[i:i+6]) for i in xrange(0, 36, 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using b directly, which will dereference to the string pointed to by b (so it results in 'l[#]', not 'l[4] or so), not b's index. Use the list.index() function to get b's index and assign to l based on that, rather than b's value

```
if ch:
    l[l.index(b)] = t
else:
    l[l.index(b)] = g
```

Comment: Thank you, you've helped a lot! It works awesome, and I get to see the little map changing ^^. Except... for some reason the lower area (below the center) never seems to change... ever. I do not know why, do you?

Comment: @PlazmotechBinary, it doesn't work because `index` returns the index of the _first_ occurrence of whatever's in `b`. So later occurrences never get changed. It's better to use `enumerate`.

Comment: @senderle is correct. I hadn't considered that the lookup with list.index() will only find the first occurance. I would update my answer, but there're two better ones already that point out the right way to do this. Better to leave this around to show a possible pitfall, no?